# Firing a event before the default action of jqm

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to call a function before the default action of the jqm
here is my work

```
<a href="#defaultpanel" data-role="button" id="sd" data-inline="true"
data-icon="bars">Default panel</a>
```

When I click the button a left panel opens,now my requirement is to call another function before showing the left panel so I wrote this

```
$('#sd').live('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  alert("g");
});
```

But still the alert is not fired,but the left panel is shown.Please help me.Thank u

Comment: if you're using jQuery 1.7 and higher, use `.on` instead of `.live`. edit: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/9WQsY/

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to the [beforeopen](http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/#event-beforeopen) event:

```
$("#defaultpanel").on("panelbeforeopen", function() {
    alert("g");
});
```

Comment: @user, is `#defaultpanel` created dynamically (i.e. not present in the page markup)? In that case, you would have to delegate the event.